# Why does MATLAB fmincon ignore non-linear constraints?

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to use MATLABs fmincon function to solve a non-linear problem of which I know that it can be solved in a different way very easily but I want to use fmincon (you might not need the following detailed information about the problem but I provided them in case you need):

Function f(x) is a quadratic function with its vertex at point (5|1).

`f(x)=0.1(x-5)^2+1    for   0<=x<=5`

Function g(x) is a polynom of order 4 with its vertex at Point (c|0).

`g(x)=(x-c)^4         for   0<=x<=c`

Function h is just a line on the x axis.

`h=0                  for   c<=x<=5`

[image: image of the graphs]

I want to minimize the Area between the function f(x) and the two connected functions g(x) and h, in the interval [0,5]

`minimize A=2*(int(f,[0,5])-int(g,[0,c]))=55/3 - (2*c^5)/5`

Also I have the constraint that f(x) must always be 1 unit above the functions g(x) and h.

From the graph I know that the variable c must be between 0 and 2 (just a range for the fmincon function).

This is my .m file:

```
clc
clear

format long;
options = optimoptions(@fmincon, 'Display', 'iter', 'Algorithm', 'interior-point');

fun=@(x)55/3 - (2*(x(1))^5)/5;

lb = [0];
ub = [2];

[x,fval] = fmincon(fun,[0.1],[],[],[],[],lb,ub,@cons_Q6,options)
```

The constraints file looks like this (I inserted a lot of values for x with an increment of 0.1):

```
function [c,ceq]=cons_Q6(x)
c=[(0.0-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.0-5)^2
(0.1-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.1-5)^2
(0.2-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.2-5)^2
(0.3-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.3-5)^2
(0.4-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.4-5)^2
(0.5-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.5-5)^2
(0.6-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.6-5)^2
(0.7-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.7-5)^2
(0.8-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.8-5)^2
(0.9-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.9-5)^2
(1.0-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.0-5)^2
(1.1-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.1-5)^2
(1.2-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.2-5)^2
(1.3-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.3-5)^2
(1.4-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.4-5)^2
(1.5-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.5-5)^2
(1.6-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.6-5)^2
(1.7-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.7-5)^2
(1.8-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.8-5)^2
(1.9-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.9-5)^2
(2.0-x(1))^4-0.1*(2.0-5)^2
(2.1-x(1))^4-0.1*(2.1-5)^2
(2.2-x(1))^4-0.1*(2.2-5)^2
(2.3-x(1))^4-0.1*(2.3-5)^2
(2.4-x(1))^4-0.1*(2.4-5)^2
(2.5-x(1))^4-0.1*(2.5-5)^2
(2.6-x(1))^4-0.1*(2.6-5)^2
(2.7-x(1))^4-0.1*(2.7-5)^2
(2.8-x(1))^4-0.1*(2.8-5)^2
(2.9-x(1))^4-0.1*(2.9-5)^2
(3.0-x(1))^4-0.1*(3.0-5)^2
(3.1-x(1))^4-0.1*(3.1-5)^2
(3.2-x(1))^4-0.1*(3.2-5)^2
(3.3-x(1))^4-0.1*(3.3-5)^2
(3.4-x(1))^4-0.1*(3.4-5)^2
(3.5-x(1))^4-0.1*(3.5-5)^2
(3.6-x(1))^4-0.1*(3.6-5)^2
(3.7-x(1))^4-0.1*(3.7-5)^2
(3.8-x(1))^4-0.1*(3.8-5)^2
(3.9-x(1))^4-0.1*(3.9-5)^2
(4.0-x(1))^4-0.1*(4.0-5)^2
(4.1-x(1))^4-0.1*(4.1-5)^2
(4.2-x(1))^4-0.1*(4.2-5)^2
(4.3-x(1))^4-0.1*(4.3-5)^2
(4.4-x(1))^4-0.1*(4.4-5)^2
(4.5-x(1))^4-0.1*(4.5-5)^2
(4.6-x(1))^4-0.1*(4.6-5)^2
(4.7-x(1))^4-0.1*(4.7-5)^2
(4.8-x(1))^4-0.1*(4.8-5)^2
(4.9-x(1))^4-0.1*(4.9-5)^2
(5.0-x(1))^4-0.1*(5.0-5)^2
];
ceq=[];
```

As you can see, I've set the bounds for the unknown variable so that `x(1)=[0,2]` and I have set the constraints in the range [0,5] although I would only need them in the range of [0,2] because of the bounds for x(1).
Now, when I solve it like this I get a solution that doesn't fit all the constraints. But when I delete the unneccessary constraints in the range ]2;5]

```
function [c,ceq]=cons_Q6(x)
c=[(0.0-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.0-5)^2
(0.1-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.1-5)^2
(0.2-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.2-5)^2
(0.3-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.3-5)^2
(0.4-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.4-5)^2
(0.5-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.5-5)^2
(0.6-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.6-5)^2
(0.7-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.7-5)^2
(0.8-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.8-5)^2
(0.9-x(1))^4-0.1*(0.9-5)^2
(1.0-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.0-5)^2
(1.1-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.1-5)^2
(1.2-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.2-5)^2
(1.3-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.3-5)^2
(1.4-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.4-5)^2
(1.5-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.5-5)^2
(1.6-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.6-5)^2
(1.7-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.7-5)^2
(1.8-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.8-5)^2
(1.9-x(1))^4-0.1*(1.9-5)^2
(2.0-x(1))^4-0.1*(2.0-5)^2
];
ceq=[];
```

then I get the right result. Does anyone know why this happens and why MATLAB does not respect the constraints when I put them up for the whole range [0,5]?

Answer (score 1):

```
   -Your problem is more related to calculus than matlab tool
   constraints like 
   function [c]=cons_Q6(x)
   c=[x < 0; x > 0]; are just ignored by fmincon, because they are not logical 

   Technically you need to know the optimum c before solving 
   this optimization problem


   - Another issue A = int(f,[0,5])-int(g,[0,c]) = 55/6 - c^5/5 instead of 
                   A = 2*(int(f,[0,5])-int(g,[0,c])) = 55/3 - (2*c^5)/5

   Factor 2 is used whether for even whether for odd function (like cosine or since). 
   Even for those kind of function the integration interval is reduced by half

I updated your optimization function and the solution c is as follow

x = [0, c], constraint is g(x)-f(x)-1<= 0--> (x-c)^4 -0.1(x-5)^2 <=0
x = [c, 5], constraint is h(x)-f(x)-1<= 0--> -0.1(x-5)^2 <=0

c must be predefined or guessed in advance, here I supposed c = 2 
because your upper bound ub = 2
```

As a result

```
x = [0, 2], --> (x-c)^4 -0.1(x-5)^2 <=0
x = [2, 5], --> -0.1(x-5)^2 <=0
```

cons_Q6(x) is as follow

```
function [c,ceq]=cons_Q6(x)
c=[(0.0-x)^4-0.1*(0.0-5)^2;
(0.1-x)^4-0.1*(0.1-5)^2;
(0.2-x)^4-0.1*(0.2-5)^2;
(0.3-x)^4-0.1*(0.3-5)^2;
(0.4-x)^4-0.1*(0.4-5)^2;
(0.5-x)^4-0.1*(0.5-5)^2;
(0.6-x)^4-0.1*(0.6-5)^2;
(0.7-x)^4-0.1*(0.7-5)^2;
(0.8-x)^4-0.1*(0.8-5)^2;
(0.9-x)^4-0.1*(0.9-5)^2;
(1.0-x)^4-0.1*(1.0-5)^2;
(1.1-x)^4-0.1*(1.1-5)^2;
(1.2-x)^4-0.1*(1.2-5)^2;
(1.3-x)^4-0.1*(1.3-5)^2;
(1.4-x)^4-0.1*(1.4-5)^2;
(1.5-x)^4-0.1*(1.5-5)^2;
(1.6-x)^4-0.1*(1.6-5)^2;
(1.7-x)^4-0.1*(1.7-5)^2;
(1.8-x)^4-0.1*(1.8-5)^2;
(1.9-x)^4-0.1*(1.9-5)^2;
(2.0-x)^4-0.1*(2.0-5)^2;
-0.1*(2.1-5)^2;
-0.1*(2.2-5)^2;
-0.1*(2.3-5)^2;
-0.1*(2.4-5)^2;
-0.1*(2.5-5)^2;
-0.1*(2.6-5)^2;
-0.1*(2.7-5)^2;
-0.1*(2.8-5)^2;
-0.1*(2.9-5)^2;
-0.1*(3.0-5)^2;
-0.1*(3.1-5)^2;
-0.1*(3.2-5)^2;
-0.1*(3.3-5)^2;
-0.1*(3.4-5)^2;
-0.1*(3.5-5)^2;
-0.1*(3.6-5)^2;
-0.1*(3.7-5)^2;
-0.1*(3.8-5)^2;
-0.1*(3.9-5)^2;
-0.1*(4.0-5)^2;
-0.1*(4.1-5)^2;
-0.1*(4.2-5)^2;
-0.1*(4.3-5)^2;
-0.1*(4.4-5)^2;
-0.1*(4.5-5)^2;
-0.1*(4.6-5)^2;
-0.1*(4.7-5)^2;
-0.1*(4.8-5)^2;
-0.1*(4.9-5)^2;
-0.1*(5.0-5)^2;
];

ceq=[];

The constraints in the range ]2;5] are very necessary keep them

clc
clear

format long;
options = optimoptions(@fmincon, 'Display', 'iter', 'Algorithm',... 
'interior-point');

fun=@(x)55/6 - (x^5)/5;

lb = [0];
ub = [2];

[c, A] = fmincon(fun,[0.1],[],[],[],[],lb,ub,@cons_Q6,options)
```

solution :

```
c = 1.257432726024430


A = 8.537951710969493
```

Comment: Since f(x) needs to be 1 unit above g(x) the 'missing' number 1 gets eliminated as we have it on both sides of the equation. Or do you mean something else? Also how does c=1.99 fit all the constraints? If you insert c=1.99 in the first constraint it results in a positive number and therefore the constraint is not respected, right?

Comment: Since the function h is always a minimum of 1 unit under the function f (see image) there is no need for the other constraints ensuring that h is a minimum of 1 unit under f. Also c = 1.31 can not be the optimal solution since f(x=0)=3.5 and g(x=0, c=1.31)=2.95 and this means that f(x) is only around 0.5 above g(x,c). The right solution is c=1.257 which I calculated with fmincon. But I only get the solution when not having constraints for x>2.

Comment: I just found out where the problem was. If the constraints go all the way from x=0 to x=5 there is no solution for the problem since the function g would always have a higher value as funtion f in some point. I just didn't realize it earlier since I was just looking at the left symmetric side of function g. When we limit x to a maximum of 2, then there exists a solution.

Comment: Check the new update. You need to make sure your problem formulation is right before using fmincon. Give it the right function to optimize and the necessary constraints to expect the optimum solution .